# Setting decimal places in an MDB database

Tags: ms-access, ado.net, dao

Part of a project I am working on is programmatically create a series of MDB files which will be the final deliverables. The specs from the client ask for some fields in the tables to have 3 decimal places.

I create the mdb files using python at first, and then to be able to alter the columns to DECIMAL (10,3), I use ADODB (C#, .NET 4.0) - as i couldn't find something suitable in Python. Problem though is that this will not be enough for the client. They want to open the MDB and in Design Mode to see the Decimal places for these fields to be set to 3. If they are not, the file is not accepted.

It has now taken me the best part of 3 days trying to come up with a solution. One likely candidate was DAO and the Field2 object but this object has so far eluded me. I am using the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Objects but Field2 doesn't seem to be part of the assembly. And dont even know if this will actually do what is required...

Does anyone know a way to do this? Don't care if its DAO, ADO, OLEDB or any other 3 letter acronym to be honest? How can I get from this:

[image]

to this - PROGRAMMATICALLY??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you how to do this in VBA/DAO, which may give you some ideas. You must append the property first:

```
sSQL = "create table testX (id counter, anumber decimal(10,3))"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute sSQL

Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim fld As dao.Field

Set db = CurrentDb

Set tdf = db.TableDefs("testX")
Set fld = tdf.Fields("anumber")
'fld.Properties("DecimalPlaces") = 3
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DecimalPlaces", dbByte, 3)
tdf.Fields("anumber").Properties.Append prp
```

Comment: Thanks @Remou Would that apply to an existing table as well? I'll give this a go anyway

Comment: Yes, it would. The point of the lines at the top are to illustrate that the table has been created with ADO, but the decimal places are set with DAO. Note, however, that you will get a trappable error if the decimal places property has already been created.

Comment: You are a star! That worked very nicely in C# Many, many thanks. Think next time I will be using this site much earlier :-)

Comment: Did you find a way to do this was ADOX or did you have to do this in DAO as shown in the example?

Comment: @mapoholic it worked nicely in C# then doesn't post solution in C# for n00bs like me :C - can you post the solution even thought this was 4 years ago lol...

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub DBF_SetDecPoints(ByVal DBNom As String, ByVal DBTab As String, ByVal Campo As String, ByVal NDEC As Short)
    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim TD As DAO.TableDef
    Dim FD As DAO.Field
    Dim PP As DAO.Property

    If DBF_Exists(DBNom, DBTab, Campo) Then
        'Call DBF_SetProperty(DBNom$, DBTab$, Campo$, "Format", DaoText, "Fixed")
        DB = DAOEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(DBNom)
        TD = DB.TableDefs(DBTab)
        FD = TD.Fields(Campo)
        PP = FD.CreateProperty("Format", DaoText, "Fixed")
        On Error Resume Next
        FD.Properties.Append(PP)
        FD.Properties("Format").Value = "Fixed"
        PP = FD.CreateProperty("DecimalPlaces", DaoByte, NDEC)
        FD.Properties.Append(PP)
        FD.Properties("DecimalPlaces").Value = NDEC
        On Error GoTo 0
        DB.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for sharing your knowledge.  Your answer would be better if you would explain *why* it works and what part of it is specificaslly applicable to the OP's question.