# change decimal places of a currency column through alter table statement in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Am using MS Access 2007 Database, I have a Currency type column in a table with Decimal places 2.Now I need to change the decimal places(in table design) to 3 through alter table query. Is there any solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting decimal places in an MDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779750/setting-decimal-places-in-an-mdb-database)

Comment: An ALTER TABLE statement to change decimal places can be executed in VBA but it will change Currency data type to Number with Decimal field size and Currency format.